# Customer Account Registration Form

Tags: customer, customer-account, register, create

I am relatively new to magento. I would like to place customer account registration page in two columns. Preferably, left side with First Name, Last Name, Email and password. Right Side, Address Fields.

I could find below code from layout/customer.xml for RWD theme.

Customer Account Registration Form

```
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Is it possible to make changes to above code and split the forms into two columns?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot split the form into 2 columns via the layout xml. The term "columns" has a different meaning it Magento. A column acts like a container for the elements inside it and you need all the fields to be in the same container because they should be wrapped in a form.
But what you can do is to edit the template `customer/form/register.phtml` and change the markup to fit your needs.  Copy the file from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` to your theme `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml`keeping the same path and work your magic in the clone.

Comment: Cool! I will give it a try.

Comment: I have placed register.phtml under the above path but I think it still considers base/default file! any comments? I have also removed file from `app/design/template/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` but no changes at frontend. cleaned cache, still no changes!

Comment: Turn on the template path hints to see what templates are actually used. Most probably the on from the `persistent` folder is used. Don't ask why magento uses this. I'm really puzzled myself about why the `persistent`  module works this way.

Comment: Yes, you are right. template path shows 'persistent'